# Can I change my terminal environment to bash shell using a script and then execute other commands after changing the shell in the same script?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, superuser

I am trying to write a script that sets my main terminal to use bash shell. I know the #!/bin/bash will call all the commands in the script to be run with the bash shell but what I want is a script that specifically that changes the shell of my terminal to bash.

for example: (this is how my terminal looks like when it is opened.)

```
$
```

when i want to set the terminal to bash I manually type the bash command and press enter.

```
$bash
```

outcome:

```
[tyg@rooto ~]$
```

The problem is if I write a script using the above command it works but any command after the bash command in the script fails to execute.
for example

```
#!/bin/bash
bash
echo "setting terminal environment to bash"
echo "success"
```

output:

```
[tyg@rooto ~]$
```

Expected output: (something like this)

```
[tyg@rooto ~]$ setting terminal environment to bash
[tyg@rooto ~]$ success
```

or (Like this)

```
[tyg@rooto ~]$
[tyg@rooto ~]$ setting environment
[tyg@rooto ~]$ success
```

any of the above is what I assume should be expected. Why are the two echo commands in the script failing to execute and is there a fix to this. Thanks

Comment: best to **edit your question** and explain why you have both `#!/bin/bash` and then `bash`. Normally, you don't need the 2nd one. Are you trying to do somethi8ng more elaborate than your posted code? Good luck~!

Comment: @African_king : Your question is not about programming, and as such should better be asked at [superuser](https://superuser.com/), but as a general idea: Virtually every terminal emulator can be configured which shell to use, and once you are inside a shell, you can always either replace the shell by a different one (using `exec`) or create a different shell as a child process, in which you continue to work.

Comment: @shellter : I am trying to incorporate this into an ssh login I also added more details to the question if that okay

Comment: @user1934428 : yh thanks I just checked out super user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#!/bin/bash` will invoke the shell in which the subsequent script commands will be executed and upon completion, the shell will be gone.  This is how you "execute commands in the changed shell"

`bash` on line 2 opens a 2nd bash shell in which your `echo` command is being executed. It too goes away on completion of the script - that's why you don't see the output as expected.

Yes, you can execute a "bash" script in any shell as long as the first line has the correct shell you want.

By removing the `bash` on line two, you'll see your output.

Comment: Sorry if this doesn't exactly answer your question.

Comment: thanks for making the effort.

Answer (score -1):

#### Example 1

```
#!/bin/bash

bash << "EOT"
echo "setting environment"
EOT
```

#### Example 2

Add this code to a sample script, test.sh, then launch it:

```
#!/bin/bash 

echo "Shell: $$"
bash << "EOT"
echo "Shell: $$"
EOT
echo "Shell: $$"
```

#### Result:

```
Shell: 569 # Current shell
Shell: 570 # Shell in your new enviroment
Shell: 569 # Back to old shell
```

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work

Comment: It does. See my example 2. Upgrade bash if it still wont work.